# Viewing logs for internet access through Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-event-log

I am just getting started with using Windows Event Viewer to view logs. I am not sure where to look for logs related to activities like:

`(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://www.somesite.com/file.txt", "file.txt")`

Does the event viewer even record such events? Does it record it both on success and failure? I looked through the Application, Security, Setup and System logs, but couldn't find anything in there. I even checked the Powershell section of Event Viewer, but again, it returned nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you show is related to **PowerShell**. However, PowerShell logging:

- Is not activated per default
- Require at least PowerShell 4.0 or 5.0 to be installed
- Require to turn on PowerShell audit features manually or by GPO (see image below):

[image: Audit settings features]

Before activating audit features, ensure to be aware of the 3 different logging existing features (details in table below):

- Module logging
- Script block logging
- Transcription

[image: Logging features capacities]

Once logging has been activated, you will find related logs in **Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational** event logs folder.

Also find below a list of the different events IDs produced during logging:
[image: event ID list]

> So to answer your questions in a nutshell:
>
> 1. Read this very good documenation from FireEye ([source](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2016/02/greater_visibilityt.html))
> 2. Ensure your system is compliant
> 3. Upgrade to PowerShell 4 or 5 if necessary
> 4. Enable logging manually or by GPO
> 5. Look into the logs and search for the proper event

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Michel's great response, take a look at [this blog article](https://www.eventsentry.com/blog/2018/01/powershell-p0wrh11-securing-powershell.html), it explains PowerShell event logging in great detail, including ways to mitigate.

Answer (score 0):

Windows event logs don't register web activity events.
But if it's your own Powershell script, you can simply log these events yourself (into EventLog - see Write-EventLog or just into a file).

Alternatively, you can use any third-party internet activity tracker or enable logging in Windows firewall. But they commonly log all events (not only from Powershell).